# Build Fields for Sub Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called `Person` that owns `Venue`. The classes are as followed:

app/models/person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_acessible :height
     has_one :venue
end
```

app/models/venue.rb

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_acessible :location
end
```

Now, if I wanted to make a form, it'd be like this if `Person` didn't `has_one` `Venue`:

```
<%= form_for :person do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :height %>
<% end %>
```

How would I do this if I wanted to create the `Venue` object for this `Person` with this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In this case, you'd use `fields_for` to emulate the rendering of fields of your sub model.